# Aside from the Addins folder, where (and how) do VS add-ins get deployed?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, add-in, extensibility

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible to deploy a Visual Studio add-in to its own folder, rather than using the Addins folder. I know it's possible - tools like ReSharper do it - but I cannot find any info on how to tell VS where the add-in is located. Can someone explain to me how it's done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Carlos Quintero has your answer - http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008001.aspx - no suprise there...